# Split Multidimensional array into two arrays on the basis of keys

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am very new to PHP World and stuck with this problem from last three days.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sim_id] => 15
            [Tarrif_code] => D34
            [rental] => USD 345
            [service_provider] => Vodafone
            [incoming_calls] => 3.2 /sec
            [local_outgoing] => 3.2 /sec
            [international_call] => 3.2 /sec
            [company_name] => Airtel
            [local_text] => 
            [international_text] => 
            [data] => 2G
            [sim_type_id] => 1
            [offer_short_descrption] => 
            [validity] => 
            [dialing_instruction] => 
            [recharge_instruction] => 
            [usage_warning] => 
            [country_id] => 1
            [type] => Prepaid
        )
)
```

and the result should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sim_id] => 15
            [Tarrif_code] => D34
            [company_name] => Airtel            
            [rental] => USD 345
            [service_provider] => Vodafone
            [country_id] => 1
            [type] => Prepaid


   [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [international_call] => 3.2 /sec
            [incoming_calls] => 3.2 /sec
            [local_outgoing] => 3.2 /sec)
            [local_text] => 
            [international_text] => 
            [data] => 2G
            [sim_type_id] => 1
            [offer_short_descrption] => 
            [validity] => 
            [dialing_instruction] => 
            [recharge_instruction] => 
            [usage_warning] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: And what is the pattern behind this? + Show us your current code/attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding data provided in question:

```
$arr[0] = new stdClass;

$arr[0]->id = 1;
$arr[0]->name = 2;
$arr[0]->state = 3;
$arr[0]->land = 4;

$arr2[0] = new stdClass;

foreach($arr[0] as $k => $v)
{
    if (!in_array($k, array('id', 'land')))// array of keys for first object
    {
        $arr2[0]->{$k} = $v;
        unset($arr[0]->{$k});
    }
}

var_dump($arr[0]);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($arr2[0]);
exit;
```